# Move Values from Rows to Columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get values stored like this in columns  in sql server like below:

```
Mon| Tue| Wed| Thu| Fri| Sat| Sun
30 |  20| 30 | 10 | 30 | 15 | 25
```

to something like this:

```
Mon|30 
Tue|20 
Wed|30
Thu|10
Fri|30
Sat|15
Sun|25
```

Sample code will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is t1:
t1(mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun)

Here's your answer:

```
select 'Mon' as day, mon as number from t1
union all
select 'Tue', tue from t1
union all
select 'Wed', wed from t1
union all
select 'Thu', thu from t1
union all
select 'Fri', fri from t1
union all
select 'Sat', sat from t1
union all
select 'Sun', sun from t1
```

In your result set, then, you'll have two fields: "day" and "number" as specified in the answer.