# SQL Server - Query for a strange table

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, sql-server-2008

i had a table called products, and

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

The struct of the result, it's what makes this interesting:

```
PRODUCT_1 | PRODUCT_2 | PRODUCT_3 | PRODUCT_4 | PRODUCT_ 5 
$  10.00  |  $ 20.00  |  $ 25.00  |  $ 30.00  | $ 35.00
```

I know i know, who the hell design a table like this?
But unfortunately, this is what i have. What i need to do, is copy this table from SQL Server to PostgreSQL through a C# application. In PostgreSQL i have a new structure for this table, but i dont know how can i make a query could give me a structure like this:

```
Product    |    Cost
--------------------
Product_1  |  $ 10.00
Product_2  |  $ 20.00
Product_3  |  $ 25.00
Product_4  |  $ 30.00
Product_5  |  $ 35.00
```

Comment: is this limited to 5 products only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example**

```
Select B.* 
 From  products A
 Cross Apply (
                values ('PRODUCT_1',[PRODUCT_1])
                      ,('PRODUCT_2',[PRODUCT_2])
                      ,('PRODUCT_3',[PRODUCT_3])
                      ,('PRODUCT_4',[PRODUCT_4])
                      ,('PRODUCT_5',[PRODUCT_5])
             ) B (Product,Cost)
```

**Returns**

```
Product     Cost
PRODUCT_1   10.0000
PRODUCT_2   20.0000
PRODUCT_3   25.0000
PRODUCT_4   30.0000
PRODUCT_5   35.0000
```

**EDIT - For a Dynamic Approach Where You Don't Have to Specify Fields and Field Names**

```
Select Product = C.Item
      ,Cost    = C.Value
 From  products A
 Cross Apply ( Select XMLData=convert(xml,(Select A.* for XML Raw)) ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('FieldsTo','Exclude')
             ) C
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use Unpivot as below:

```
select * from Products
unpivot(cost for Product in ([Product_1],[Product_2],[Product_3],[Product_4],[Product_5])) p
```

For dynamic script:

```
declare @cols varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @cols = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(Column_Name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Table_name = 'Products' for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Set @query = '  select Product, Cost from Products '
Set @query += ' unpivot(cost for Product in ( ' +@cols + ')) p '

Select @query --Uncomment and execute below query if your created script is good
--exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Plus 1 -  I wasn't positive unpivot was available in 2008.  It has been a long time.

Comment: it is available from 2008... I am big fan of your SQL querying approaches... Yours are always unique.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the grin

Answer (score 2):

Try this nice and simple thanks to Alisa [Move Values from Rows to Columns in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316888/move-values-from-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server-2008)

```
select 'Product' as Product, PRODUCT_1  as Cost from products
union all
select 'Product_1  ', PRODUCT_1  from products
union all
select 'Product_2', Product_2   from products
union all
select 'Product_3  ', Product_3   from products
union all
select 'Product_4', Product_4   from products
union all
select 'Product_5  ', Product_5 from products
```

Result:

```
Product    |    Cost
--------------------
Product_1  |  $ 10.00
Product_2  |  $ 20.00
Product_3  |  $ 25.00
Product_4  |  $ 30.00
Product_5  |  $ 35.00
```